# Can not parse XML SOAP response Python Zeep

Tags: python, xml, soap, zeep

I receive this response from a SOAP service, but I am not able to parse the response. I want to read the values for gtin.

```
client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl)
#The soap call receives 4 arguments, the last argument is the response format
soapCall = client.service.GetStock(1,104500009,104500009,"XML")
```

Here is how the response looks like in pydev debugger in Eclipse:

```
GetStockResponse: {\n    'GetStockResult': '<DRSStock>\\n    <Shop  Number="1">\\n         <s v="104500009"  vi1="13"  vi2="1001"   gtin="5018746023776"  q="1" />         <s v="104500009"  vi1="31"  vi2="1001"  gtin="5018746004058"  q="0" />         <s v="104500009"  vi1="32"  vi2="1001"
```

I tried to parse the response using this, but I get the error below:

```
xml_data = etree.parse(soapCall)
```

The error:

```
TypeError: cannot parse from 'GetStockResponse'
```

Comment: What is the type of soapCall? Could you try like this etree.parse(soapCall['GetStockResult'])? I think that you pass a dict to the parser

Comment: Indeed that was the case, I am able to access the value with soapCall['GetStockResult']